# Transparency Report Standards

Tags: privacy

Are there any standards around what information should be included in a transparency report?  I have reviewed what other companies have provided and would like to follow suit but I'm not aware of any standard.

If there is no standard, please feel free to provide suggestions for a baseline of information that is helpful to users of a service.  My thoughts are to release what information is gathered when using any one of our services, or when connecting to our network (we provide Internet access).

Answer (score 3):

This is going to differ across industry, e.g., educational institutions have been implementing a lot of [EDUCAUSE](http://www.educause.edu/library) related frameworks/standards/guidelines which would differ from say a day trader who may follow [FINRA](https://www.finra.org/) which may not even allow for non employees to connect. Ultimately, a privacy officer along with an attorney should be tasked with drawing this up. If it were me, and I had to start it, I'd go with what [government monitors](http://www.howto.gov/web-content/digital-metrics) (+1 if you quickly thought about the NSA)... and I'd go from there aiding the corp. attorney since ultimately, you want to be in the legal clear.

Comment: +1 for Privacy Officer and lawyer. Reports answer questions. You include in the report only the answers to the questions you are required to answer. This needs careful guidance.